# Cannot find -lgmodule-2.0

Tags: compiling, cross-compilation

I try to cross compile `bluez-utils-3.36` from the sources. But i always get this error after executing `make`command.

`/home/mbc/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmodule-2.0`

i tried `locate gmodule-2.0`, this is the output:

```
/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.a
/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.la
/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so
/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.2400.1
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/gmodule-2.0.pc
```

Is the file `/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so` the searched file?
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cross-build for arm using host (x86?) libraries in `/usr/lib`.  You need to acquire from somewhere or build by yourself all dependencies of bluez for arm, and place them in the path your cross toolchain can find.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Im a bit confused. The Host is the machine, on which the application is supposed to run. So my host is  `arm-none-linux-gnueabi`. The target is the machine on where i build and compile, isn't it?